# Wrong View is being returned

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview, layout-inflater

I have a layout for my gird item which contains a linear layout and in that a textView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_all_white_rounded_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ui_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_social_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Family  Friends"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_text"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

When i call 
`inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_grid_row, parent, false);` from adapter it returns view of type

```
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
```

instead of a linear layout.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolderCategories holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_grid_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderCategories(mContext, rowView);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderCategories) rowView.getTag();
    }
    MainCategory data = mAllData.get(position);
    holder.updateView(data.getCategoryName());

    return rowView;
}
```

I am not able to figure why its returning some other view instead of a liner layout

Comment: can you post the full code of the xml file?

Comment: i have posted, but its not visible. can you edit my question?

Comment: Try cleaning your build, not that I think it will work but it can't hurt :P

Comment: Change   "if (convertView == null) " to   " if (rowView == null)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_grid_row, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Activity layout file in which i have added the grid view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/colorAppTheme">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

just removed the `android:gravity="center"` form GridView and its working fine. 
Don't have any idea how its related but i thought to post the answer.